# Optimization to general Linear problem form

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I don't know how I can write this minimization problem like a general LP:

Given m vectors $v_1,v_2...v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and m numbers $t_1,..,t_m \in \mathbb{R}$, we want a vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$|v_i^Ty-t_i| \leq D \ \ \ for \ i \in \{1,...,m\}$, with minimal $D \in \mathbb{R} $

My problem is to see what exactly are the constraints in this case. Hope you can help me

Comment: Could you add definitions, and perhaps some links, to your question? Not everyone is intimately familiar with the subject jargon :)

Comment: Equivalent LP: minimize $D$ subject to $-D\le v_i^Ty-t_i\le D$.